# Db2 contains query should return result if any matches

Tags: db2

I'm using DB2 and want to know how to solve the below problem

i have a table **user_games** and i pass the **game_name** and it should return me the **game_id**.

Eg: if i pass the **game_name** as 'Soccer, Tennis, Golf' the db2 query should return me 1 as **game_id**,  as the game_name matches tennis.

Table name: **user_games**

```
GAME_ID               GAME_NAME

=======              ========== 

1                    Tennis 

2                    Badminton 

3                   Basketball
```

I tried using contains in db2

```
    SELECT * FROM user_games WHERE CONTAINS(GAME_NAME,'Soccer, Tennis, Golf') = 0
```

i get the error as

SQL Error [42724]: A text search option is not installed or not properly configured..

Please advise how to achieve the result using query or as hibernate criteria.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`contains` is only functional if DB2 Text Search or DB2 Net Search Extender is correctly installed and configured AND the database is enabled for text search ([Enabling Text Search](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/dm-0810shettar/)). Try starting text search and enabling the database with:

```
db2ts start for text
db2ts enable database for text connect to mydb
db2ts "create index game_name for text on user_games(game_name) connect to mydb"
db2ts "update index user_games for text connect to mydb"
```

Now the contains function for game_name should work. But, if you don't have that functionality, you'll need to resort to another approach. For example:

```
select * FROM user_games 
WHERE GAME_NAME in ( 'Soccer', 'Tennis' ,'Golf' )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only contains into game_name :

```
SELECT * FROM user_games 
WHERE 'Soccer, Tennis, Golf' like '%' || GAME_NAME || '%'
```

or like this :

```
SELECT * FROM user_games 
WHERE position (GAME_NAME IN 'Soccer, Tennis, Golf')>0
```

If you want only is contain into game_name with ',' delimiter :

```
SELECT * FROM user_games 
WHERE 
'Soccer, Tennis, Golf' like trim(GAME_NAME) || ',%' or
'Soccer, Tennis, Golf' like '%, ' || trim(GAME_NAME) || ',%' or
'Soccer, Tennis, Golf' like '%, ' || trim(GAME_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM user_games WHERE CONTAINS(GAME_NAME,'Soccer, Tennis, Golf') = 0

**[CONTAINS](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/dm-0810shettar/)** function is built-in search function  available for **full text search** in DB2.

> SQL Error [42724]: A text search option is not installed or not properly configured..

You are getting an error because DB2 Text Search is not installed or not correctly configured on this server.

> Please advise how to achieve the result using query or as hibernate criteria.

Ensure that either DB2 Text Search or DB2 Net Search Extender is **[correctly installed and configured](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/dm-0810shettar/)** and that the database is enabled for text search.